# xml schema : how to create element with string pcdata and one attribute

Tags: xsd

I am trying to create a very simple element and am not able to define it the way I had wanted in my schema. (I'm using oXygen to edit the schema, and am going by the fact that it is giving me errors when trying to define the element)

I want to create an element like this:

```
<sc:col-hd id="1">Col hd name</sc:col-hd>
```

but I'm not able to define it in the schema. What I ended up doing was creating the element with two @atts, like so:

```
<sc:col-hd id="1" col-name="bean"/>
```

and the def for that is this:

```
        <xsd:element name="col-hd" maxOccurs="unbounded">

            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="col-name" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
```

but if I wanted to define it as in the first example, how would I do that? xsd:simpleContent is the only allowable element just before the atts (according to oXygen), but that, according to the error has to have a base that points to a complex type.

There has to be a way to define the element as in the first example. The second compromise is actually ok for me, but it's bugging me that I can't find a way to do it as in the first example.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `xsd:simpleContent` *can* extend a simple type, the following should do what you need:

```
    <xsd:element name="col-hd" maxOccurs="unbounded">

        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to designate an `xsd:string` `simpleType` and then add your attribute(s) via `xsd:extension` child-elements.

[XML Schema for SimpleType and Attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504994/xml-schema-for-simpletype-and-attribute)